# where does wildfly store jdbc driver jar file?

Tags: sqlite, wildfly, wildfly-8

I'm using wildfly 8.2.  I registered the sqlite driver and created a datasource for it already.  It's connected fine and I can see it in the standalone.xml.

But when I search under the "wildfly-8.2.0.Final" directory, I can't find the "sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar" file.

Do you know where wildfly store the physical jar file?

Thanks

Comment: How did you "register" the driver? Added it as a module? Deployed it?

Answer (score 1):

You can just put the Jar-File of the driver in the Deployment-Folder of the Wildfly. "/wildfly-path/standalone/deployments" The files in this folder will always deploy on startup.

https://bitbucket.org/xerial/sqlite-jdbc/downloads/sqlite-jdbc-3.8.7.jar

Comment: Thanks but everything is started up fine for me. I can see in the console that it loaded up the jdbc driver fine. I'm just curious where it put the jar file.  I can't find it anywhere under the <wildfly installation path> directory.

Comment: The h2-jdbc-driver is the only one, which is included by default. Normally you have to add other specific driver, like postgresql or mysql. Do you deploy a maven-project or you added the driver to your lib-path? You can post your datasource and persistence-file if you like.